# Access application of one container from another with link/port forward

Tags: docker

Please suggest how can I launch a service of a container from another container.

Details here:

Docker HOST1 is running 2 containers: CONT1 and CONT2.

CONT1 is based on ubuntu and apache. It has got IP 172.17.0.2. Here port 80 is exposed in Dockerfile.

```
vi Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER debu3645@yahoo.com
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install iputils-ping traceroute apache2
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

CONT2 is based on ubuntu only. No apache in this container.It has got IP 172.17.0.4.

I have "linked" CONT2(source) with CONT1(receiver). I can ping CONT1 from CONT2 and vice versa.

```
sudo docker run -d --name CONT1 debapcping  (debapcping image contains ubuntu, apache)
sudo docker run -d --name CONT2 --link CONT1:aliasCONT1 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

From HOST1:: I can launch apache web service from IE using http://172.17.0.2:80

But my intention is to launch apache of CONT1 via CONT2 i.e. how can I forward the request from CONT2 to CONT2 so that apache service of CONT1 can launch on providing CONT2 IP and port e.g. http: //172.17.0.4: 1234

I tried IP NAT but it throws following error:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.17.0.4 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80

iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)

 sudo docker info
Containers: 8
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 10
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 32
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: active
 NodeID: i9b555lgjovk5ep3fln0j8roi
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 10.0.2.17
 Manager Addresses:
  10.0.2.15:2377
  10.0.2.18:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init

containerd version: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1
runc version: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-110-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.49 GiB
Name: Consul2
ID: 3I44:ZHAW:R6BO:NF2J:YCLQ:ZRW6:ULOE:AKJQ:HD7M:EMPE:7Z35:H4KY
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https:  //  index.docker.io /v1 /
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 10.0.2.18:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Permission denied issue: the issue solved after adding "--privileged" option while launching docker container, something like below:

docker run -it --name debrcvr8 --link debsrc:ALIdebsrc --user root --privileged -p 5555:80 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash

And for the forwarding issue: I managed to fix this issue with the below NAT port forwarding commands on CONT2:

root@ae06859a194e:/#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp  --dport  -j DNAT --to-destination :
root@ae06859a194e:/# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete command that was run on CONT2(172.17.0.4) to access the apache webserver running on CONT1(172.17.0.2:80)

In the docker host machine (which runs CONT1 and CONT2), I used the following link to access apache :  http://172.17.0.4:6666/

root@ae06859a194e:/# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.17.0.4 --dport 6666 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80root@ae06859a194e:/#

root@ae06859a194e:/# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE